# start and stop tomcat via command prompt

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, tomcat

Im currently using **tomcat 6.0.18**.  I have installed tomcat server and set the `CATALINA_HOME` variable in the environment variables. Inside the tomcat installation location under the `bin` folder, there is no `startup.bat` or `shutdown.bat` file available. There are only two exe files: `tomcat6.exe` & `tomcat6w.exe`. I would like to know how to start the tomcat server via command prompt.

I tried executing the below command

```
C:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat6.0\bin>tomcat6.exe start
```

The `start` command works fine. But I'm unable to stop the server using the command

```
C:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat6.0\bin>tomcat6.exe stop
```

But the `stop` command does not stop the server. It only starts the tomcat server.

Both the commands 'tomcat6.exe start' & 'tomcat6.exe stop' starts the tomcat server. I would like to know what options should I use to stop the tomcat server via command prompt.

Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: After tomcat installation, in the bin folder I see only four files bootstrap.jar, tomcat6.exe, tomcat6w.exe, tomcat-juli.jar. There is no catalina.bat file available.

Comment: I have used the apache-tomcat-6.0.18.exe file to install this tomcat version. I dont have any zip package available.

Answer (score 1):

If tomcat server is 64 bit and system is 32 bit server wont start...Check the system type also when configuring

Answer (score 0):

I have installed tomcat using the following steps on windows..

**Step1:** uninstall current tomcat

**step2:** go to https://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi
       and download the zipped version and extract it somewhere in your         drive you want to install .Their is no need for installation using
       exe , as you can directly extract and run

**step3:** set the CATALINA_HOME , try to run  startup.bat , if JAVA_HOME 
          is properly  set , It should start running .

**step4:** Well If you face any problems while starting .bat file(for windows) try running the  file using command prompt , It will show you error if any

hope that helps!!.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But I would like to know the solution for the existing tomcat version that Im using. There are other versions of tomcat available, but im intrested in arriving at a solution for the tomcat version that Im using. which is tomcat 6.0.18

Comment: May be what I think is your installation didn't happen correctly due to which the files are missing from bin folder .

Answer (score 0):

In your bin directory there is a file called startup which is an executable. Please execute that.After you have run that please check the following url http://localhost:8080/. If you have installed tomcat successfully then you will get a message.

Answer (score -1):

In your bin directory there is a file called startup which is an executable. Please execute that.